# Empty string response due to bad synchronism

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, dialogflow-es

I started a simple Agent and I added a basic Intent named "**myIntent**" to it. I enabled fulfillment through the Firebase inline editor and, following the istructions I added a function named " **myFunction**" to the base one provided. This function contains a sample HTTPS GET request to https://reqres.in/api/users/2 .
My goal is to add a response to my intent based on the response provided by the GET call to the external API.

#### The script

```
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const https=require('https');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

function myFunction(agent){
    
    var info='';
    var options = {
         host: `reqres.in`,
         path: `/api/users/2`,
         method: 'GET',
         headers: {'Accept':'application/json'}
    };
    
    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
         console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
         console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    
         let data='';
    
         res.on('data', (d) => {
           data+= d;
         });
    
         res.on('end', () => {
           console.log(data);
           let jsonObject= JSON.parse(data);
           info=jsonObject.id;
        
           console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
         });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
       console.log('ERROR');
       console.error(e);
    });

    agent.add(JSON.stringify(info));
    req.write('End of request');
    req.end();  


}
    
 

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('myIntent',myFunction);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

The intent is correctly triggered, but my problem is that the agent response is always an empty string.
[image]

I have not much experience with http calls, function callbacks but I think that problem is the line

```
 agent.add(info);
```

at the end of my script is executed before of the end of the http call.
I make variuos attempts inserting a promise inside `myFunction` following https://www.promisejs.org/, but all of them carry only error messages. 
Every kind of help will be appreciated, I understand the problem but I can't fix it in any way.

P.S: [agent.handleRequest docs reference](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/docs/WebhookClient.md#WebhookClient+handleRequest)

#### My failed attempt using Promise

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const https=require('https');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

 
 function myFunction(agent){
    var info='';
    var p=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      
        var options = {
        host: `reqres.in`,
        path: `/api/users/2`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Accept':'application/json'}
        };
    
        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers:', res.headers);
            let data='';
    
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            data+= d;
        });
    
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log(data);
            let jsonObject= JSON.parse(data);
            info=jsonObject.id;
        
             console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.log('ERROR');
            console.error(e);
        });

        req.write('End of request');
        req.end();
        resolve(info);
    });
    
    p.then((agent)=>{
        agent.add(info);
    });

    }
let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('myIntent',myFunction);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation of the first snippet, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still *immediately* doing things with `info` - now resolving the promise - instead of doing them from the asynchronous callback. Put the `agent.add()` call or the `resolve()` call in the `end` handler so that it will happen only after the data is complete:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    var options = {
        host: `reqres.in`,
        path: `/api/users/2`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Accept':'application/json'}
    };

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers:', res.headers);
        let data='';

        res.on('data', (d) => {
            data+= d;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log(data);
            let jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
            resolve(jsonObject.id);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        reject(e); // don't forget this
    });

    req.write('End of request');
    req.end();
});

p.then(info => {
//     ^^^^ the fulfillment value that you passed to resolve()
    agent.add(info);
}, err => {
    console.log('ERROR');
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. Now there are two errors in console: "Unhandled rejection" and "unknown response type at WebhookClient.add (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:225:13) at p.then.info (/user_code/index.js:63:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)".

Comment: @HJuls2 I don't know what `dialogflow-fulfillment` module you are using or what is causing "unknown response type" errors within it, my answer only solved your problem of passing `info` to `agent.add`

Comment: Ok, I tested printing the value in console instead of using WebhookClient.add and I saw that the promise works correctly. The problem is only on Dialogflow fulfillment function

Comment: @S.Dwyer My working solution is substantially Bergi's one, but I encapsulated it in a function that returns the Promise i.e. `function_that_returns_promise.then(info =>{info=JSON.parse(info);
     agent.add(info.field)`. In this way, the "resolve" must have a json string as parameter